# What is the purpose of including sea level pressure and temperature in a METAR?

Tags: weather, flight-planning

In a METAR such as this one:

> KGOK 161553Z AUTO 18011KT 4SM BR OVC007 07/05 A3011 RMK AO2 SLP201
>   T00670050

Translated to:

> Jan 16, 1553Z, Automated. Mist, Wind from 180° at 11 knots, 4 statute
>   miles visibility, Ceiling is Overcast at 700 feet, Temperature 7°C,
>   Dewpoint 5°C, Altimeter is 30.11. Remarks: automated station with
>   precipitation discriminator sea level pressure 1020.1 hectopascals
>   hourly temp 6.7°C dewpoint 5.0°C

Why would I want/need to know, or what would I do with, this information in the remarks section:

> sea level pressure 1020.1 hectopascals hourly temp 6.7°C dewpoint
>   5.0°C

Comment: Are you asking about why the values are present at all (07/05 A3011 is the first time, and absolutely essential information in the report), or why are they given twice (SLP201 T00670050 is the second time, as a remark, with a bit of extra precision)?

Comment: You forgot “baby rain” (aka mist) :)

Answer (score 6):

Note that A3011 (30.11 inHg) is 1019.6 hPa, which is lower than 1020.1 (SLP201).

The small difference is because SLP (unlike QNH) is corrected for the 12-hour mean temperature at the reporting station, giving more accuracy to the meteorologists.

So SLP is *not* a metric conversion of the altimeter setting in inHg to be used by pilots accustomed to hPa – it's for meteorology, not flying.

Likewise for the more precise temperature reading in the remarks.

---

Further reading: https://www.wingsbywerntz.com/520-metar-slp-sea-level-pressure

Answer (score 3):

The sea level pressure allows pilots to calibrate their altimeters to make sure they are accurate. KGOK is 1069 feet elevation, if a pilot were to set their altimeter to 1020hpa (or 30.11 inches of mercury as used in the US, that's the A3011 in the METAR) then their altimeter would read 1069ft at ground level.

Comment: Ok so it is helpful to know that those two things are related (A3011 and the RMKs about sea level pressure) and I know what I would do with the A3011 to set my altimeter; what causes me to ask this question was: why the extra information if it is already communicated with A3011?  I am not sure that it is at all useful beyond what A3011 tells me.

Comment: Whatever site is translating that METAR for you is converting the measurements @user2325243.

Comment: +1 answer  Above Sea Level  and Above Ground Level may apply differently.  Local flight would set altimeter for AGL.  Cross country would set ASL (or AGL of destination).  Changing weather will also factor in.  I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) flight levels are in ASL.

Answer (score 3):

It is additional information for reference use. A pilot in the US will not typically use the additional information unless they have an altimeter calibrated in hPa, but a meteorologist might be accustomed to working in hectopascals (or millibars). The additional temperature/dewpoint data is also more precise -- to the tenth of a degree C.

Comment: The hPa is also useful for international pilots arriving from locations where they typically use hPa instead of inches of Hg. All airliners can switch between the two units, but pilots like what they use most often.

Comment: Why not use Q1020 in the main section, as done in other countries, rather than putting it (in a different format!) in the remarks section?

Comment: @StephenS, the remarks section has extra precision. I suspect it is there for the benefit of meteorologists, because pilots don't need it.

Comment: @StephenS, "Why not use Q1020 in the main section, as done in other countries..."  Because we are Americentric!  ;)

Comment: @Gerry Not all airliners in all places... a common exception was the mechanical Airbus standby altimeters which only had one unit, so they often had a decal somewhere with the conversion. (Even more annoying if the plane originally came from the wrong place and the airline was too cheap to swap out the unit)

Answer (score 0):

The two pressure values given in the METAR string are clearly not simply the same value just being repeated in different units.  See for example this METAR, given in coded and decoded forms (source: https://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/index?submit=1&station_ids=KIAB&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=2&std_trans=translated&chk_tafs=on ).  The second value is the more accurate one because it is corrected for non-standard temperature and this is the value that would be used to obtain "calibrated altitude", but the first value is the one that pilots actually use to set their altimeter to get "indicated altitude".

> METAR text:   KIAB 271456Z AUTO 25007KT 10SM CLR 22/12 A3004 RMK AO2
> SLP168 T02190119 51005 $

> Conditions at:    KIAB (MCCONNELL AFB , KS, US) observed 1456 UTC 27 May 2022

> Temperature:   21.9°C (71°F)

> Dewpoint: 11.9°C (53°F) [RH = 53%]

> Pressure (altimeter):  30.04 inches
> Hg (1017.4 mb) [Sea-level pressure: 1016.8 mb]

> Winds: from the WSW
> (250 degrees) at 8 MPH (7 knots; 3.6 m/s)

> Visibility:    10 or more miles
> (16+ km)

> Ceiling:   at least 12,000 feet AGL

> Clouds:    sky clear below
> 12,000 feet AGL

> Weather:    SOME DATA ABOVE MAY BE INACCURATE!!! "$" is
> an indication the sensor requires maintenance

Also addressed here -- [Why are the airport pressure values for "altitude" (inHg) and "sea level" (mb) slightly different on the NOAA web sites?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83341/why-are-the-airport-pressure-values-for-altitude-inhg-and-sea-level-mb-s?rq=1)